# Resolve conflicts in JGit with no changes

Tags: eclipse, git, jgit, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a file which is in conflict state. In order to resolve it, I change its content, add it to index again and then commit the changes. It works nicely when there are real changes. But when I want to keep my file content untouched it doesn't work. If I just remove the conflict marks, Jgit throws this exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: No changes
```

It seems correct since the local file technically wasn't changed, but how to specify that this is the final version I want?

Just to be clear: the same issue occurs also in Eclipse. Just follow these steps:

1. checkout a project;
2. make a simple change and commit it;
3. make a remote change that will be in conflict with the local one;
4. run the pull command to get the remote change;
5. run the merge tool. It does nothing if you don't change anything, so
   make a change like cut and paste the same piece of code;
6. save the file and add it to index;
7. try to commit the file. Eclipse won't list it, since there is no
   real change, but it should have a change to represent the "merged"
   state;
8. try to push to upstream. Now you have a "MERGING_STATE" issue to
   deal with.

What's wrong with these steps?

Comment: You didn't commit your merge.

Comment: @m0skit0 I didn't commit the merge because there wasn't such option. If you try to commit from anywhere, Eclipse shows the message "No files to commit".